# How to create interrelated sliders?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, interactive

Say I want a slider that controls the value of $x$ and another slider that controls the value of $2x$, how would I go about it?

Comment: Is it purely abstract question or you need this for something else? I am curios what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Need this for a tool that helps me to play around with speed (split time) / time / distance for the rowing machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This?

```
{Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 10}], 
 Slider[Dynamic[2 x, Set[x, #/2] &], {0, 20}]}
```

[image]

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) explains, under More Information, that "`Dynamic[expr,f]` makes interactive operations not change `expr` except by virtue of the evaluation of `f[val,expr]`. ". Otherwise, Mathematica attempts to assign a value to `2x`.