# Interdependent controls in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, scheduling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create interrelated sliders?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-to-create-interrelated-sliders)
>   [locking a value when manipulating variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/locking-a-value-when-manipulating-variables)

I need to create a `Manipulate` with two control parameters which are linked by some mathematical relationship. So the user can decide to use either control and when that control is changed, the other will change too.

The example below works as required, using `If` statements to determine if one of the parameters has been changed and setting the other parameter appropriately.

Although this code works, I suspect there is a better/neater approach which avoids the need to "manually" keep track of `oldx` and `oldy`. What is the best way to do it?

```
oldx = oldy = 0;
Manipulate[
If[x != oldx, y = 1/x; oldx = x];
If[y != oldy, x = 1/y; oldy = y];
{x, y},
{x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 0.1, 10}]
```

Comment: I am almost positive this question is a duplicate yet I cannot find it.  Does this seem overly familiar to anyone else?

Comment: I suppose I was thinking of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1373/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would say this is similar to this one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/locking-a-value-when-manipulating-variables/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I did search before I posted the question, but didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could consider something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 {x, y},
 {x, Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = 1/#) &], {.1, 10}] &},
 {y, Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = 1/#) &], {.1, 10}] &},
 Initialization :> ({x, y} = {1, 1})]
```

#### Edit V10

Since V10 one can use a shorter form:

```
Manipulate[
    {x, y}
  , {x, .1, 10, TrackingFunction :> ((x = #; y = 1/#) &)}
  , {y, .1, 10, TrackingFunction :> ((y = #; x = 1/#) &)}
  , Initialization :> ({x, y} = {1, 1})
]
```

Comment: Thanks Heike, this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 9):

You could also build a custom `Manipulate`-like object using sliders

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{x, y},
    Column[{
        Grid[{
            {"x", Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = 1/#) &], {0.1, 10}], Dynamic[x]},
            {"y", Slider[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = 1/#) &], {0.1, 10}], Dynamic[y]}
        }],
        Panel[{Dynamic[x], Dynamic[y]}, ImageSize -> 300, Background -> White]
    }], ImageSize -> 300
]]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you want the 2nd `ImageSize` to be an option to outside `Panel`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hmm, I guess that isn't necessary. I don't actually remember why I had it any more, heh. I was just correcting an [accepted suggested edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51707) that fixed a typo (missing `]`) but was applied in the wrong place and messed up the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
{Slider[Dynamic[x], {0.1, 10}], 
 Slider[Dynamic[1/ x, Set[x, 1/#] &], {0.1, 10}]}
Dynamic[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]