# Coupled controls in a Manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I have a paragraph

```
Manipulate[
    expr,
    { {a, 1}, 1, 4, 1},
    { {b, 2}, 2, 5, 1}
]
```

and I want variable b to be bigger than a at all times.

I have searched for help on this and one thread on this site mentions the functions `Manipulate` and `Dynamic`, but as I am new to Mathematica I don't fully understand the solution - and as I won't need Mathematica too much in the future it's not expedient for me to read through 5 page tutorials on both functions until I maybe get how both work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this or linked topics answer your question?: [Interdependent controls in Manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5409/5478)

Comment: `Manipulate[a + b, {{a, 1}, 1, 4, 1}, {b, a + 1, a + 6, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign dependencies between the Manipulate variables. For example:

```
Manipulate[If[b < a, {a, b} = {Min[a, b], Max[a, b]}]; {a, b}, 
          {{a, 1}, 1, 4}, {{b, 2}, 2, 5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/coupled-controls-in-a-manipulate-expression#comment356576_132135) by [Alan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19530/alan) with a [`TrackingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) to ensure that also the value of `b` is increased whenever necessary:

```
Manipulate[a + b,
 {{a, 1}, 1, 4, 1, TrackingFunction -> (a = #; If[b <= a, b = a + 1]; &)},
 {b, a + 1, a + 6, 1}]
```