# Interactive Manipulators acting badly

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, interactive

How do I fix the bad behavior of Manipulator? This is in regards to this [Interdependent controls in Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5409/interdependent-controls-in-manipulate) question. Heike' s code does not work right on the first click when specifying the Manipulator increment and using Appearance -> "Open" for both Manipulators. For instance, a first click on "Step Forward" does not produce the increment x +=.1. Also, closing y, then incrementing x looks okay until you open y. This bad behavior only occurs on the first click after evaluating the cell, but a solution should be found.  Here is the code:

```
 Manipulate[{x, y},
  {x, Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = 1/#) &],
      {.1, 10, .1}, Appearance -> "Open"] &},
  {y, Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = 1/#) &],
      {.1, 10, .2}, Appearance -> "Open"] &},
  Initialization :> ({x, y} = {1, 1})]
```

The error persists no matter what is done. This simple version without Dynamic does not increment by .1 on the first click on x+ or y+.

```
   Manipulate[
   If[xh != x, xh = x; y = 1/x; yh = y];
   If[yh != y, yh = y; x = 1/y; xh = x];

   {x, y},
   {{x, x0, "x: "}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Open"},
   {{y, y0, "y: "}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Open"},
   Initialization :> {xh = x = x0 = 1; yh = y = y0 = 1/x;},
   TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you use `DynamicModule` for want you are trying. Like so.

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1, y = 1},
 Column @
  {Dynamic @ {x, y},
   Manipulator[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = 1/#)&], {.1, 10, .1}, Appearance -> "Open"], 
   Manipulator[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = 1/#)&], {.1, 10, .2}, Appearance -> "Open"]}]
```

[image: demo]

IMO easier than `Manipulate` in this case. But if your heart is set on using `Manipulate`, then

```
Manipulate[
  {x, y},
  {x,
   Manipulator[
     Dynamic[#, (x = #; y = 1/#)&], {.1, 10, .1}, Appearance -> "Open"]&}, 
  {y, 
   Manipulator[
     Dynamic[#, (y = #; x = 1/#)&], {.1, 10, .2}, Appearance -> "Open"]&}, 
   Initialization :> ({x, y} = {1, 1})]
```

[image: manip]

Comment: Did you notice that the Initialization :> ({x, y} = {1, 1} does not work corectly in V12, and that the increments don't work correctly in V11.3 on the first click of +.

Comment: @kmutiny. I don't have V12, so I know nothing of the behavior of the Manipulate form in that version. As for what you say about a problem with the increments in V11.3, it is not clear to me what you mean. In any case, as I said in the answer, I don't recommend using a `Manipulate` form to solve your problem.