# Manipulate dynamic PopupMenu drop down selector

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I am trying to get a `PopupMenu` in `Manipulate` that will be dynamically updated. The code that seems correct is below:

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  a = Table[
    Association[
     Table[Association[
       Table[ToString@i -> RandomInteger[50], {i, 0, 3}]], 10]], 10]
  },
 Manipulate[
  {x, y},
  {{x, First@Keys@First@a}, Keys@First@a, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
  {{y, First@Union[#[x] & /@ a]}, Union[#[x] & /@ a], 
   ControlType -> PopupMenu}
  ]
 ]
```

but instead I get this:

[image]

I guess I should do something like `SynchronousUpdating` to make it work but still have no luck

Comment: Does it answer you question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1199/5478

Comment: I have made it a duplicate because it boils down to creating dynamic controllers which linked answer addresses. Let me know if you disagree. Here is another related topic: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5409/5478