# K linked controls within Manipulate

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, constraint

This question is related to "[Locking a value when Manipulating variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/locking-a-value-when-manipulating-variables)" and several other questions on linked controls, but differs enough that new ideas and techniques are required, I believe.

I would like to make an interactive demonstration using `Manipulate[]` in which the number of variables and corresponding (slider) `Controls` and--most importantly--their functional relations, are dynamically set by a user-specified integer `k` in the `Manipulate` display.  Each of the `k` `Controls` governs a scalar probability variable (`0 < P[[i]] < 1`), and the sum of all `k` probabilities is equal to 1.0.  (The variables represent true probabilities of dependent events.)

If there were just two variables `P[[1]]` and `P[[2]]` (or here `P1` and `P2` for simplicity) then

```
Manipulate[
   P2 = 1. - P1;  
   {P1, P2},    
{{P1, .5, "P1"}, 0, 1}, 
{{P1, 1, "P2", (P2 = 1. - #) &}, 1, 0 }]
```

would work.  Note especially that you can adjust either slider `Control` and the other slider `Control` moves appropriately, i.e., to always guarantee that the sum obeys `P1 + P2 = 1.0`.

A related approach to the two-variable case is given in the Mathematica online tutorial `IntroductionToDynamic`.

The problem gets more difficult for `k > 2`, however.  One can dynamically set the number of variables and their controls by `k`, but implementing the appropriate dynamic constraints automatically (given a set `k`) has proven rather difficult.  First note that if one variable is dynamically changed by the user, the settings of the other `k-1` variables is not unique; there are an infinite number of configurations of the other variables that ensures the full sum is equal to 1.0.  The constraint I desire will eliminate such ambiguity by the following:  When the user clicks on one control (`P1`, say) and slides and releases it, each of the other variables changes so as to preserve their ratios that existed when the `P1` control was clicked.

An example:  Suppose `k = 3` and the current variables are `{.7, .2, .1}`. The user clicks on the `P1` slider and adjusts its value to `P1 = .85`.  The other two variables must remain in their initial `.2/.1` ratio as well as ensure that the sum of all variables is `1.0`.  In this case, the variables will be `{.85, .1, .05}`.  Suppose instead the user had clicked on `P2` control and changed it from `P2 = 0.2` to `P2 = .3`.  Then the `P1` and `P3` variables must remain in the ratio of .7/.1 and ensure the full sum of variables is 1.0.  In this second case the variables will thus be `{0.6125, .3, 0.0875}`.

The generalization to arbitrary `k` is simple mathematically, but has proven tricky to automatically implement within `Manipulate[]`.

(A footnote:  When the `Manipulate[]` function is initialized or `k` changed by the user, each variable should be initialized to the same value, `P1 = P2 = ... = 1/k` in the iteration brackets.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
update[p_, pi_, i_] := ReplacePart[p (1 - pi)/Total[Drop[p, {i}]], i -> pi];
Manipulate[
 p,
 {{n, 3}, Slider[Dynamic[n, (n = #; p = ConstantArray[1./n, n]) &], {2, 10, 1}] &},
 {{p, ConstantArray[1./3, 3]}, ControlType -> None},
 Control[
  {{p, ConstantArray[1./3, 3]}, Dynamic[
     Column @
       Table[With[{i = i}, 
        Slider[Dynamic[p[[i]], (p = update[p, #, i]) &],
          {$MachineEpsilon, 1 - $MachineEpsilon}]],
        {i, n}]
     ] &}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The main idea is to have a vector of probabilities `p` and update the vector with `update` whenever one of the probabilities is changed.  The number `n` of probabilities was just so I could test it on different lengths of `p`.

Comment: Very nice, and almost there.  It would be nice if when your n is changed the probabilities are re-set to P1 = P2 = ... = 1/n.  It would also be nice (but admittedly not specified in the problem statement) that the labels on the sliders be P1, P2, etc.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yeah, I meant to do that (1/n).  Brain hiccup, I guess.  I'll think about the labeling....

Comment: Elegant.  Thanks.

Comment: Wait!  When I set n=4, my interface acts as if n=2; when I set n=5, my interface acts as if n=3.  What's going on?

Comment: Yep.  Your final edited version works.  Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This will label each control: `Dynamic[Column[Table[With[{i = i}, Control[{{p, ConstantArray[1./3, 3], Dynamic["P" <> ToString[i]]}, Manipulator[Dynamic[p[[i]], (p = update[p, #, i]) &], {$MachineEpsilon, 1 - $MachineEpsilon}] &}]], {i, n}]]]`  Alignment with other controls is missing. It seems the `Dynamic` in `Dynamic["P" <> ToString[i]]` is necessary, even though nothing changes. I've other ways, but each has its own slight awkwardness.