# Dependent Manipulate sliders

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

I would like to use dependent sliders in `Manipulate`.
First slider `K0` should be independent and varied from `Kmin` to `Kmax`.
Two others sliders `K1` and `K2` should dependend on `K0` so that `K1*K2 == K0` should be always true. Is it possible?

Comment: Strangely, I've failed to find any related post about this fairly basic question (maybe this about [interrelated sliders](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1373/89)), and the Documentation Center only has a *somewhat* related [example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0scsql7f3nhsixgc-ef4srw).

Answer (score 11):

As always, here is the more customizable `DynamicModule` version:

```
DynamicModule[{k0, k1, k2, kMin = -1, kMax = 1},
 Panel[Grid[{
   {"k0", Slider[Dynamic[k0, (k0 = #; k2 = k0/k1) &], {kMin, kMax}], Dynamic@k0},
   {"k1", Slider[Dynamic[k1, (k1 = #; k2 = k0/k1) &], {-1, 1}, Exclusions -> {0}], Dynamic@k1},
   {"k2", Slider[Dynamic[k2, (k2 = #; k1 = k0/k2) &], {-1, 1}, Exclusions -> {0}], Dynamic@k2},
   {Panel[Dynamic@Grid[{
         {"k0", k0}, {"k1", k1}, {"k2", k2}, {"k1*k2", k1*k2}}, 
        Alignment -> Left], ImageSize -> {250, 90}], SpanFromLeft}
   }, Alignment -> Left], ImageSize -> {300, 200}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that division by zero is handled by `Exclusions -> {0}`.

Comment: Use the `Exclusions` option for `Slider` to prevent landing on zero and division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing you might try

```
 k0Old = 1; k1Old = 1; k2Old = 1; kMin = 1; kMax = 2;
 Manipulate[
   If[k1 != k1Old || k0 != k0Old, k2 = k0/k1; k1Old = k1; k0 = k0Old];
   If[k2 != k2Old, k1 = k0/k2; k2Old = k2;];
      {k0, k1, k2, k1 k2}, {k0, kMin, kMax}, {k1, 0.1, 10}, {k2, 0.1, 10}]
```