# Alternate controls in manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

Is there a way to have two controls that govern a single variable in a `Manipulate`?
Specifically, I am using a `Locator` to select an `{x,y}` coordinate, but I would also like the user to be able to directly specify `x` and `y`, in `InputField`s.

Similar questions have been asked, but not with `Manipulate` and not with a 2D variable.

Comment: Yes, just put in the controls with the same variables.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28768/3066) instructive.

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
Manipulate[
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[{x, y}], Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}]],
 {{x, 0}, InputField},
 {{y, 0}, InputField}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]