# How to remove all buttons in Manipulate, except the input fields?

Tags: manipulate, customization, display

By default, when you click the small "+" symbol, at the right of a slider (in Manipulate and Animate), you get an input field and several buttons (play, pause, etc).  How do you remove *all* buttons for *all* the sliders in a Manipulate box, except the input fields ?

The documentation isn't obvious at all for customization like this, and searching the site didn't helped much.  Sorry if I missed something related.

Comment: So you want the slider AND the input field? If you can get by without the input field and work just with the slider, you could use `ControlType -> Slider`.

Comment: @MarcoB, I still need the input field for values that are hard to select with a slider.

Comment: Related: ([28768](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28768/27951)).

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 6, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}}]` ?

Comment: @Algohi, nice !  This is working !  Is there a way to define these options "globaly" inside the Manipulate code, without having to add these options to each slider separately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With[{maniOpts = Sequence[
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
    AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}, ImageSize -> Large
    ]
  },
 Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)]/b, {x, 0, 6}], 
  {a, 0, 6, maniOpts}, 
  {b, 1, 5,  1, maniOpts}]
 ]
```

This is what I do in similar cases.

Comment: Why the **With** ?  I tried using just `maniOpts = Sequence[
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
    AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}, ImageSize -> Large
    ];`, and it's working great, apparently after a first try.

Comment: @Cham Manipulate is meant to work across MMA sessions, so if you are not including `maniOpts` inside or injecting those options directly, `maniOpts` will be forgotten when you  open this cdf/notebook in fresh session. So maybe it's not necessary but I do this from habit.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.  These options are defined only for this particular Manipulate box.  If I close this notebook or if I open another nootebook with another Manipulate, it is normal that everything is forgotten by MMA.  Compiling a given code would erase all the previous definitions, since I use **Clear["Global`*"]** at the beginning of all of my projects.  Well, this is the way I work with MMA.  Maybe this isn't ideal ?  Is there a potential conflict/problem I'm not aware of, with this method ?

Comment: @Cham `Manipulate` is `HoldAll` so if you just put there ``Global`maniOpts`` its definition won't be found when you open notebook in fresh session, unless you evaluate whole notebook but the point is to have self contained Manipulate output. You can read more about related things in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html, especially on FE ownership of DynamicModule variables.

Comment: Kuba, the document you linked cannot be found.

Comment: @Cham Strange, [here it is again](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html). P.s. in this case maybe even the first chapter is better.

Answer (score 2):

Roll your own controls:

```
Manipulate[
  a b c d,
  Grid[{
    {Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 100}], "a =", Left],
     InputField[Dynamic[a], ImageSize -> Tiny]},
    {Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[b], {-50, 50}], "b =", Left], 
     InputField[Dynamic[b], ImageSize -> Tiny]},
    {Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[c], {-10, 30}], "c =", Left],
     InputField[Dynamic[c], ImageSize -> Tiny]},
    {Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[d], {0, 1}], "d =", Left],
     InputField[Dynamic[d], ImageSize -> Tiny]}
  }]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The **InputField** would replace the slider's label.  This is fine.  These elements would be placed inside a **Row** directive to make a line.  But how do you place several of them (Slider + InputField) on top of each other ?

Comment: @Cham Yes, you can arrange their position as you wish using e.g. `Row`. But what do you mean by *on top of each other*?

Comment: I mean a vertical stack of standard sliders (as what is done by default), but each one having its Input field on their right using **Row**.

Comment: @Cham Take a look at the new version of my answer.

Comment: It's all working great !  I prefer Algohi's settings, since it's making my code much simpler and easier to understand.  Both answers are good, though.  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with a general setting, you can do it like this:

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}];
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 6}]
```

You can either save the options and return them back:

```
saveoption = Options[Manipulator];
SetOptions[Manipulator, saveoption];
```

Or you can use `ParallelEvaluate` to get fresh kernel:

```
SetOptions[Manipulator, First@ParallelEvaluate[Options[Manipulator]]]
```

Or as [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) mentioned, use:

```
SetOptions[Manipulate, AppearanceElements -> Automatic]
```

[image: example Manipulate]

Comment: Very nice !  This would simplify my code a lot, with **ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},** added to the **SetOptions**.  Can this **SetOptions** be reset using **Clear["Global`*"]** ?

Comment: @Cham, use `SetOptions[Manipulate, AppearanceElements -> Automatic]` to reset back to the default.

Comment: Aw, I see that it's also resetting all the other Manipulate codes I've done.  So this cannot be set locally, for a given Manipulate ?  Do I have to add **SetOptions[Manipulate, AppearanceElements -> Automatic]** to all of my other Manipulate codes ?

Comment: @Cham, just append the options if you only want it to apply to a single `Manipulate[]`: `Manipulate[(* stuff *), Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}, ImageSize -> Large]`.

Comment: It appears to work, but **Appearance** and **ImageSize** are shown in red in my code !  The compilation appears to be normal, and no warning/error messages.  ??

Comment: Hmm, nope, after restarting MMA, the ImageSize, Appearance and AppearanceElements aren't recognized anymore.

Comment: @Cham put it inside variable spec: `{a, 0, 6, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"},  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}}`

Comment: @Kuba, yes it's working, but I would like to simplify the code a bit, if I was able to declare all the options as a separate "parameter".  I tried this : `OptionsMani = {
   ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},
   AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
   };` and pasted `OptionsMani` inside the variable specs but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Cham I posted an answer, it should fit your needs.