# Modifying the manipulator in manipulate

Tags: manipulate

When ones click on the little cross in manipulate, it opens as

[image]

Could it be possible to keep only the set number box, and the 3 first boxes ( - > +)? If have looked to AppearanceElements but I do not think it makes to work. There is a partial answer here [How to remove all buttons in Manipulate, except the input fields?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109875/how-to-remove-all-buttons-in-manipulate-except-the-input-fields) but it keeps the slider.

Comment: Kuba, I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AppearanceElements` is indeed what you need:

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 0.5, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "StepLeftButton", 
    "PlayPauseButton", "StepRightButton"}}]
```

Produces:

[image] --> [image]

Your problem was probably that you specified `AppearanceElements` for the `Manipulate` itself rather than the `Manipulator` for `x` (which is specified by `{x,...}`

### Update

Since the goal is to remove the slider and only leave the buttons and text box, it gets a little more complicated:

```
sliderLess[o : OptionsPattern[Animator]] := iSliderLess[o][##] &;
iSliderLess[o___][x_, y___] := 
 Row[{InputField[x, Number, FieldSize -> {4, 1}], Spacer[3], 
   Animator[x, y, o, 
    AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "PlayPauseButton", 
      "StepRightButton"}, AnimationRunning -> False]}]
```

The idea is to take an `Animator` and remove everything we don't want and add a `InputField` in front of it.

This can be used as standalone control:

```
sliderLess[][Dynamic[x]]
```

produces:

[image: control]

Or inside `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[x, {{x, 0.5}, 0, 2, sliderLess[AnimationRunning -> True]}]
```

As you can see, you can supply options to the `Animator` part of the control (everything but the textbox) and variable ranges are also supported (again, only for the animator).

Comment: Mathe172, it was exactly was I was expecting after elimination of the play pause button. Unfortunately, in my case it has a weird behavior: after the box, I have not the StepleftButton, the PlayPausebutton et the SteprightButton but Animator[...] the... being all the stuff of the animator. Have an idea of the reason why?

Comment: You're most likely seeing the raw `Animator[...]` object because of some syntax error. Try to compare what you're seeing with [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animator.html) - there is a list of all possible ways to specify the range, etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[x,
{{x,0,"x"},0,1,.1,
AppearanceElements->{"InputField","StepLeftButton","PlayPauseButton","StepRightButton"}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nasser and Mathe172 Many Thanks, I have not found the elements "InputField","StepLeftButton","PlayPauseButton","StepRightButton" in the doc. You are near my goal which is to remove the slider.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki I updated my answer based on your clarifications