# How to manipulate lists of parameters?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Suppose I have a function of a variable `f`, depending on some other parameters `a` and `b`, for example:

`fun[f_,a_,b_] := Sin[a*f] + Cos[b*f]`

I can plot and manipulate  this function  for some independent values of the parameters `a` and `b`:

`Manipulate[Plot[fun[f,a,b], {f, 0, 10}], {a,0,5},{b,0,5}]`

[image]

Now, suppose I would like to give discrete values to these parameters, and change both at the same time. For example,I define two points:

`A = Sequence[1,1];`

and

`B = Sequence[4,2];`

I can do this plots:

`Plot[fun[f,A], {f, 0, 10}]` or  `Plot[fun[f,B], {f, 0, 10}]`

but when I try to combine them, in order to include the possibility to manually choose between 'A' or 'B',

`Manipulate[Plot[fun[f, X], {f, 0, 10}], {X, A, B}]`

I obtain an empty plot... Instead, I would like to get a plot with two button, 'A' and 'B', corresponding to two different pairs of values for the parameters a and b.

I tried to use `List[ ]` instead of `Sequence[ ]`, but it failed to work too! I also tried `Row[ ]`, adding some braces but nothing happened... :(

What should I do? Where is the problem with my code?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at [guide/ControlObjects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ControlObjects.html) and choose what fits your needs the best. [Manipulate/Scope/Controls](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate&lang=en#) will show you how to use choosen object. And if you want to learn how to create [dependent controls here's the link.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14680/5478) - just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like this what you seek?

```
fun[f_, a_, b_] := Sin[a f] + Cos[b f];
Manipulate[
 Plot[fun[f, params[[1]], params[[2]]], {f, 0, 10}],
   {{params, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1} -> "A", {4, 2} -> "B"}}]
```

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but it sounds like you want a finite set of parameter pairs.  You could have a single variable represent each parameter pair in the manipulate, and then you could select which param to pass to your function using Part (the [[...]] operator).

[image: Manipulate with discrete parameters]

Comment: Thank you, Christopher! As you pointed out, `[[...]]` was the key to make it work! As regards the 'elegance', well... it is ok to me! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Better to use `List`s, for your `A` and `B` e.g. something like:

```
a = {1, 1}; b = {4, 2};
```

Then use `Part`, `[[i]]`, to extract the elements.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[fun[f, x[[1]], x[[2]]], {f, 0, 10}], {{x, a}, {a -> "A", b -> "B"}}]
```

`Sequence` should not be used to group items.  Most functions automatically splice in `Sequence` objects, e.g. `Head[A]` gives an error message rather than returning `Sequence`, and this can be confusing.  Indeed the definition of the control `x` in your `Manipulate` ends up being `{x, 1, 1, 4, 2}` which results in an `InputField` control rather than the more usual `SetterBar` or `Slider`. 
(It's also not a good idea to use uppercase variables as these can be reserved by the system, e.g. `N`.)

If you were to have a variable number of arguments to `fun` then you may want to use a construct like `fun[f, Sequence@@list]` to splice in the arguments but most times you would simply pass in `list` and use that in the function.

Comment: Could you explain why `Generally Sequence should be avoided in Mathematica code.` further?

Comment: Thank you, Mike, for your answer and your precious suggestions!

Comment: @belisarius - is that better?

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Perhaps `Sequence[]` should be avoided as a mean of grouping objects for later treatment, but not "in general"