# Out of range red glow on inter-dependant sliders in manipulate

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, gui-construction, version-7

In *manipulate*, I need to define two sliders : one basic slider, and a second one **for which the end value depends on the current value selected on the first slider**.  How can I achieve this in **Mathematica 7**, without having a red glow when the second parameter is out of range ?

Here's a nice MWE code to work with :

**UPDATE :**  I updated the MWE below, to show the annoying red glow on the second slider :

```
Manipulate[Plot[A Sin[2 Pi f t/12], {t, 0, 12},
PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {-1, 1}},
AspectRatio -> 1,
Frame -> True,
Axes -> True,
ImageSize -> 600],
Row[{
    Control[{{f, 1, "frequency"}, -10, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}],
    Spacer[125],
    Control[{{A, 0.1, "Amplitude"}, 0, Dynamic[Which[f < 0, 0.5, f >= 0, 1]], 0.01, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]
    }],
ControlPlacement -> Bottom
]
```

This working code shows a simple oscillation with 2 adjustable parameters : a *frequency* (from -10 to 10) and an *amplitude* (from 0 to 0.5 if f < 0, and from 0 to 1 if f > 0).  The *amplitude* parameter is partly dependant on the *frequency* selected.

When the *amplitude* is set to its max value on its slider (or close to it), and then lower the *frequency* a bit, **the amplitude slider may get a *red glow* as a warning that it is now out of range**.  I want to remove that annoying behavior.  If the *amplitude* is already close to its max value, and you lower the *frequency* to a negative value, the *amplitude* value should adapt so it's never out of range.  **It should automatically be "dragged" to its maximum value instead of find itself out of range**.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this in the manipulate code above ?

Comment: Does this [question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14680/dependent-manipulate-sliders) help?

Comment: @march, sorry I overlooked your comment.  I don't understand the answer to the question you're refering.  I'm not sure it is related.  Please, see my update above for the glitch in a partial solution.

Comment: Why not just add `A = Min[A, Which[f < 0, 0.5, f >= 0, 1]];` or equivalent before the Plot?

Comment: I didn't knew that trick.  It appears to be working great.  But just to be picky :  using this trick makes the red glow to flash for a brief moment, just before the slider gets corrected.  Can it be avoided at all ?  Is there a command to tell Mathematica to not warn the user of any out of range value ?

Comment: Feature, or bug ?  I just noticed that removing the 0.01 resolution in the control removes the glow effect, in my main code (but not in the simple example above) !  This is weird !  Now, I have many digits shown on the slider's label.  Is there a command to cut or round the label value ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I thick is to use `Dynamic["your function"]` instated of 1 in your controller.

`Control[{{A, 0.1, "Amplitude"}, 0, Dynamic["your function"], 0.01, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]`

I think this will give you want you want, (assuming the function of the end is `f+1`):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[A Sin[2 Pi f t/12], {t, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {-1, 1}},
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300],

 Row[{
   Row[{"frequency   ", 
     Manipulator[
      Dynamic[f, (f = #; A = If[A > f + 1, f + 1, A]) &], {1, 10, 
       0.01}, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}]}],
   Spacer[125],
   Control[{{A, 0.1, "Amplitude"}, 0, Dynamic[f + 1], 0.01, 
     Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}
    ]
   }],
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

Comment: This appears to work.  However, there's a glitch :  when I move the first slider (*frequency*), the other slider (*amplitude*) moves as well.  This isn't a problem.  But if the second slider is already close to its end, and I move the first slider to the left (lowering the frequency), there's a **red glow** that appears on the second slider as a kind of warning.  The *amplitude*'s end value hasen't properly adapted to the new lower frequency.  If I then move a bit the second slider, the red glow disappears.  How to fix this glitch ?

Comment: The moving in the second slide is logic because you are changing the range of the second slider. 0.5 is at the middle of slider has range from 0 to 1 but 0.5 is at quarter for range from 0 to 2. For the second issue it is not glitch it is basically A is out of range. Because when you move f to the right and then A to the right let us say you give A value of 3 for range 0 to 5, then when you move f to the left you basically reduce the range of A let use say from 0 to 1 while value of A is still 3 which will give the red singe indicating that A is out of range

Comment: Yes, I understand all this, but the red glow warning is irritating.  Is there a way to make the A slider to move away, so it's never out of range ?

Comment: @Cham see that update.

Comment: It's working, but I don't understand how and what it's actually doing yet.  I'll have to study this.

Comment: Algohi, what would you do if you want the A slider to be **from 0 to 1 only**, when frequency is negative, and A be **from 0 to 15** if frequency is positive or 0 ?

Comment: Try this `Row[{
  Row[{"frequency ", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[f, (f = #; A = If[# < 0, 1, A]) &], {-10, 10, 0.01}, 
     Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}]}],
  Spacer[125], 
  Control[{{A, 0.1, "Amplitude"}, 0, Dynamic[If[f < 0, 1, 15]], 0.01, 
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]}]`

Comment: It's working, but it's annoying : each time I simply touch the frequency slider, the amplitude jump back to 1 (or the value you set in), when the frequency is already negative.  I suspect there should be another way.

Comment: Ok good luck :)

Comment: I believe that just the second control (amplitude) should be edited.  The amplitude slider should be set to its maximum value (variable with frequency), as soon as it getting out of range, after a change of the frequency.   What do you think ?