# Stopping sliders in Manipulate going to dynamic unfeasible regions

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I am trying to use Manipulate to create a function which allows a user to play with a probability density. The following generates a static density over the range 2000 - 4000, then allows the user to calculate the probability that the variable lies between two bounds: $aLower$ and $aUpper$:

```
fShowInterval[aLower_, aUpper_] := 
 Module[{dist, p1, p2}, 
  dist = PDF[UniformDistribution[{2000, 4000}], #] &;
  p1 = Plot[dist@x, {x, aLower, aUpper}, Filling -> Axis, 
FillingStyle -> Blue, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.005]}, 
AxesLabel -> {"value $ ", "probability density "}, 
PlotRange -> {{1500, 4500}, Full}, Ticks -> {True, False}, 
PlotLabel -> N[(1/2000)*(aUpper - aLower)]];
  p2 = Plot[dist@x, {x, 1500, 4500}, Filling -> None, 
PlotRange -> {{1500, 4500}, Full}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.005]}, 
AxesLabel -> {"value $ ", "p(v)"}];
  Show[p1, p2, 
   Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{2000, 0}, {2000, 1/2000}}]}, {Dashed, 
  Line[{{4000, 0}, {4000, 1/2000}}]}}, ImageSize -> 600]]

Manipulate[
 fShowInterval[aLower, aUpper], {aLower, 2000, aUpper - 1, 
  100}, {aUpper, 2001, 4000, 100}]
```

With a result like:

[image]

The first slider stops the lower bound being higher than the upper. However, there are no corresponding constraints on the upper slider; meaning that it is possible to move this slider so that the lower bound is above the upper. I have tried modifying the Manipulate statement to:

```
Manipulate[
 fShowInterval[aLower, aUpper], {aLower, 2000, aUpper - 1, 
  100}, {aUpper, aLower+1, 4000, 100}]
```

However, I get a slew of errors, and the graph does not display.

Comment: `Manipulate[If[aLower > aUpper, aLower = aUpper - 1]; 
 fShowInterval[aLower, aUpper], {aLower, 2000, 4000, 100}, {aUpper, 
  2001, 4000, 100}]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interdependent controls in Manipulate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5409/interdependent-controls-in-manipulate) and [How to creat interrelated sliders](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-to-create-interrelated-sliders). Notice also that this situation is mentioned in the tutorial on [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) where a solution similar to the one proposed above by @belisarius is mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IntervalSlider` in version 10.0 and above.  However, you need to explicitly tell `Manipulate` to use it.

```
Manipulate[
 fShowInterval[Sequence @@ probRange], {probRange, 2000, 4000, 
  IntervalSlider, Method -> "Push", MinIntervalSize -> 1},
 Initialization :> (probRange = {2500, 3500};)]
```

[image]

`Method -> "Push"`will keep the interval endpoints from crossing one another.
`MinIntervalSize -> 1` will keep the endpoints from touching each other.

With `IntervalSlider` you can also click drag the interval by selecting the region between the two endpoints.  Not very interesting for this distribution but it will be for many others.

Comment: That's really great - thanks! Best, Ben